# Обновление  кода.

Tags: php

Часто нужно обновлять полученные данные в коде. Но громоздить куча ссылок и редиректов - не всегда бывает удобно. Можно ли как то обновить часть кода , не обновляя всю страницу? Например обновлять нужный код через каждые 30 секунд.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предложить вариант без каких-либо дополнительный LIB-ок типа jQuery ... :)
Когда-то нужно было писанину писать, вот и остался скриптик :)

```
  function createXMLHttp() {
    if(typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined") { // для браузеров аля Mozilla

      return new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if(window.ActiveXObject) { // для Internet Explorer (all versions)
      var aVersions = ["MSXML2.XMLHttp.5.0", "MSXML2.XMLHttp.4.0",
               "MSXML2.XMLHttp.3.0", "MSXML2.XMLHttp",
               "Microsoft.XMLHttp"
               ];
      for (var i = 0; i < aVersions.length; i++) {
        try { //
          var oXmlHttp = new ActiveXObject(aVersions[i]);

          return oXmlHttp;
        } catch (oError) {

        }
      }
      throw new Error("Невозможно создать объект XMLHttp.");
    }
  }

  function getRequestBody(oForm) { 
    var aParams = new Array();
    for(var i = 0; i < oForm.elements.length; i++) {
      var sParam = encodeURIComponent(oForm.elements[i].name);
      sParam += "=";
      sParam += encodeURIComponent(oForm.elements[i].value);
      aParams.push(sParam);
    }
    return aParams.join("&");
  }

  function sendRequest(link, target) {

    if(!link){
       var oForm = document.forms[0];
       var sBody = getRequestBody(oForm);
       var link = oForm.action;
    }
     if(!target)
         var target = 'divStatus';
    var oXmlHttp = createXMLHttp();

    oXmlHttp.open("POST",link, true);

    oXmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    oXmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(oXmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
        if(oXmlHttp.status == 200) {
          saveResult(oXmlHttp.responseText, target);
        } else {
          saveResult("Ошибка: " + oXmlHttp.statusText,target);
        }
      }
    };

    oXmlHttp.send(sBody);
  }

  function saveResult(sText,target) {
    var sElem = document.getElementById(target);
    sElem.innerHTML = sText;
  }
```

Собственно, код, описаный выше вставляем в <head></head> (Конечно же  заключая его в тег <script>)

Далее, Создаем

c каким-либо ID-шником. Например, `<DIV id="updateInfo"></div>`

И пишем доп. функцию для того, чтобы можно было, например, раз в 3 секунды получать контент.

```
function getContent(){
      var t = setTimeout('sendRequest("update.php", "updateInfo")', 3000);
      return t;
}
```

И заставим его срабатывать после полной загрузки страницы. Добавим в тег <body> следующее:

```
<BODY onLoad="var tOut = "getContent();" >
```

Вот и все :) А по поводу "боюсь 800 страниц" - это зря :)

Answer (score 1):

Да, конечно можно. Это делается с помощью Ajax. Вот неплохой пример [Подгрузка без перезагрузки](http://www.takein.ru/jquery/66-podgruzka-bez-perezagruzki.html)

Comment: ох :) до Ajax мне ещё далеко. :)

Comment: да на самом деле эти вещи делаются очень просто, так что, как говориться: "Глаза боятся, а руки делают!". Не бойтесь, пробуйте, задавайте вопросы тут. Поможем!

Comment: Fatahan почему так самокритично?:) <br>
Ajax это елементарно, достаточно немного времени уделить этому вопросу, 1 раз понять и стать Ajax гуру xD

Comment: а я где то видел книгу 800 страниц по Ajax - терь боюсь его как огня :) (потому что максимальную книгу по php я видел страниц на 500)

Comment: ну так не кто же не заставляет вас учить все назусть. К тому же в таких книгах, как правило, очень много информации, и на первых парах, скорее всего ненужой.